# How to test $on event with parameters in Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, events, karma-jasmine

I have the controller code:

```
$scope.$on('load', function (event) {
    $scope.getData();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and the test code:

```
it('$on load', function(event) {
    var controller=createController();
    spyOn(scope, '$on').andCallThrough();// I have also tried to spy scope getData
    scope.$broadcast('load');
    expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledwith("load");
});
```

TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function

How can I define the parameters in the call from the Unit test?

Comment: create dummy event object with stopPropagation method in your test suit.

Comment: I have tried that already but it wouldn't work

Answer (score 2):

Think of it in a different way...

If you fire the load event on the scope then u expect the getData to have been called...

Place a spy on the getData and then u can expect that function to have been called.

The way i have tested such thigns is to place the spy on the $broadcast.

```
 spyOn($scope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
 spyOn(event, 'preventDefault').and.callFake(function() {});
```

Then in the describe block

```
describe('load event', function() {

  it('should call getData method', function() {
      $scope.$broadcast('load');
      expect($scope.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Comment: It gives me:
spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for preventDefault()
or 
event.stopPropagation is not a function when I add a spy this way:
var e = jasmine.createSpyObj('e', [ 'stopPropagation' ]);

Comment: did u declare a empty function at the top?

var event = {preventDefault: function() {}};

Comment: yes I did that, keep getting this  event.stopPropagation is not a function.